# How to make sure Synfony Entity is loaded to trigger postLoad event?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I'm new to Symfony and following [the Jobeet tutorial](http://jobeet.symfony.gr.jp). I'm trying to inject Container into Entity using service listener and `postLoad`. The purpose is to use [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/) to write a thumbnail image in `@ORM\PostPersist`. The problem is that the Job entity is not loaded on some routes and then `postLoad` is not triggered. So, the container which is used in `@ORM\PostPersist` is not available.

According to the tutorial, there are two routes where `PostPersist` run:

- `job/create`
- `job/update`

I found that the Job entity is not loaded and `postLoad` is not triggered on `job/create`. The route `job/update` is fine and the container is injected. I posted some code snippets of

- services.yml
- JobListener.php
- Entity\Job.php
- JobController.php

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    ibw.jobeet.entity.job.container_aware:
        class: Ibw\JobeetBundle\Doctrine\Event\Listener\JobListener
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Doctrine/Event/Listener/JobListener.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Doctrine\Event\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class JobListener
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    protected $container;

    /**
    * @param ContainerInterface @container
    */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if (method_exists($entity, 'setContainer')) {
            $entity->setContainer($this->container);
        }
    }
}
```

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Entity/Job.php**

```
// ....
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadTmpRootDir(), $this->logo)) {
        $this->moveAndResizeImage();
    }

    $this->file = null;
}

private function moveAndResizeImage($filter = 'primary')
{
    $path = $this->getWebTmpPath();
    $target = $this->getAbsolutePath();

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $container = $this->container; 
        // got problem here. $container is null for /job/create
        // but it is okay for /job/update
        $dataManager = $container->get('liip_imagine.data.manager');
        $filterManager = $container->get('liip_imagine.filter.manager');

        $image = $dataManager->find($filter, $path); 
        $thumb = $filterManager->applyFilter($image, $filter);

        file_put_contents($target, $thumb->getContent());

        unlink($path); // remove the temp client original image
    }
}
// ...
```

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Controller/JobController.php**

```
// ...
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Job();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ibw_job_preview', array(
            'company' => $entity->getCompanySlug(),
            'location' => $entity->getLocationSlug(),
            'token' => $entity->getToken(),
            'position' => $entity->getPositionSlug()
        )));
    }

    return $this->render('IbwJobeetBundle:Job:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
// ....
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `prePersist` in the event listener class to make sure the container is available before persist. The **LiipImagineBundle** services are called on `postPersist`. I renamed `JobListener` to `MyListener`. Here is my working code:

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
ibw.jobeet.event.mylistener:
    class: Ibw\JobeetBundle\Listener\Event\MyListener
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Listener/Event/MyListener.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Listener\Event;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

use Ibw\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job;

class MyListener
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    protected $container;

    /**
    * @param ContainerInterface @container
    */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $this->injectContainer($eventArgs);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $this->injectContainer($eventArgs);
    }

    protected function injectContainer(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof Job) {
            $entity->setContainer($this->container);
        }

        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('IbwJobeetBundle:Job');
        if ($entity instanceof Job) {
            $repository->setContainer($this->container);
        }
    }
}
```

There may be a better way to handle this. If you have, please post an answer. I know that injecting the whole container is a bad practice. I will update to inject the required services only later.